# CSS não carrega na build estática (next export)

Tags: css, react, next.js, export

Estou usando yarn create next-app, para o meu primeiro projeto de site em React. Então usei o export para gerar o site estático e subi a pasta "out" no servidor para ver o resultado. Mas aparentemente todo o css está sendo ignorado. A documentação fala que não precisa nenhuma configuração, alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Erro de principiante. Eu subi a pasta "out" e ela estava alterando o caminho onde o next coloca o css. Subindo o conteúdo dela diretamente no servidor funciona.